# How to configure the system to choose apps to open links/files in one click?

Tags: default-applications, system-apps

Every time I want to open a link or a file it asks me to choose which app to use and whether I'd like to use this app always or this time only. I want to be given the choice every time so I always click "just once". Can I hide the "just once"/"always" choice so that I'd be able to choose apps in one click, always assuming "just once"?

PS: I have no idea what tags to add to this question, please add some if you do.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what version of Android you are running, I am not sure since when this has been possible (At least since Android 6.0) I myself am on Android Nougat (7.0) Developer Preview 5 with a Nexus 6P. And when I go to ***Settings -> Apps -> Top Right Gear*** there are a number of items I can choose from to select an app which will open by default. Also I can get a list of all my apps to see which ones open certain links and which do not. This is also in this settings menu. I can not however change which links they do or do not open.

Items I am able to change however include:

- List item
- Browser
- Phone
- And SMS app

Tl;dr: Depending on your Android version this is possible for some apps, but not for every link you will ever open on your Android device with the apps you have installed.